# Where is my code hanging (in an infinite loop)?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, infinite-loop, pythonplotter

I am new to Python and trying to get this script to run, but it seems to be hanging in an infinite loop. When I use ctrl+c to stop it, it is always on line 103.

```
vs = 20.05 * np.sqrt(Tb + Lb * (y - y0)) # m/s speed of sound as a function of temperature
```

I am used to MatLab (from school) and the editor it has. I ran into issues earlier with the encoding for this code. Any suggestions on a (free) editor? I am currently using JEdit and/or Notepad.

Here is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ANSI -*-
import numpy as np 
from math import *
from astropy.table import Table 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from hanging_threads import start_monitoring#test for code hanging
start_monitoring(seconds_frozen=10, test_interval=100)

"""Initial Conditions and Inputs"""

d = 154.71/1000 # diameter of bullet (in meters) 
m = 46.7 # mass of bullet ( in kg)
K3 = 0.87*0.3735 # drag coefficient at supersonic speed 
Cd1 = 0.87*0.108 #drag coefficient at subsonic speed
v0 = 802 # muzzle velocity in m/sec 
dt = 0.01 # timestep in seconds

"""coriolis inputs"""
L = 90*np.pi/180 # radians - latitude of firing site
AZ = 90*np.pi/180 # radians - azimuth angle of fire measured clockwise from North
omega = 0.0000727 #rad/s rotation of the earth

"""wind inputs""" 
wx = 0 # m/s
wz = 0  # m/s

"""initializing variables""" 
vx = 0 #initial x velocity 
vy = 0 #initial y velocity 
vy0 = 0
y_max = 0 #apogee 
v = 0
t = 0
x = 0

"""Variable Atmospheric Pressure"""
rho0 = 1.2041 # density of air at sea-level (kg/m^3) 
T = 20 #temperature at sea level in celcius
Tb = T + 273.15 # temperature at sea level in Kelvin
Lb = -2/304.8 # temperature lapse rate in K/m (-2degrees/1000ft)- not valid above 36000ft
y = 0 # current altitude 
y0 = 0 # initial altitude
g = 9.81 # acceleration due to gravity in m/s/s 
M = 0.0289644 #kg/mol # molar mass of air
R = 8.3144598 # J/molK - universal gas constant

# air density as a function of altitude and temperature 
rho = rho0 * ((Tb/(Tb+Lb*(y-y0)))**(1+(g*M/(R*Lb))))

"""Variable Speed of Sound"""

vs = 20.05*np.sqrt(Tb +Lb*(y-y0)) # m/s speed of sound as a function of temperature

Area = pi*(d/2)**2 # computing the reference area 
phi_incr = 5 #phi0 increment (degrees)
N = 12  # length of table

"""Range table"""
dtype = [('phi0', 'f8'), ('phi_impact', 'f8'), ('x', 'f8'), ('z', 'f8'),('y', 'f8'), ('vx', 'f8'), ('vz', 'f8'), ('vy', 'f8'), ('v', 'f8'),('M', 'f8'), ('t', 'f8')]
table = Table(data=np.zeros(N, dtype=dtype))

"""Calculates entire trajectory for each specified angle""" 
for i in range(N):
    phi0 = (i + 1) * phi_incr

    """list of initial variables used in while loop""" 
    t = 0
    y = 0
    y_max = y
    x = 0
    z = 0
    vx = v0*np.cos(radians(phi0))
    vy = v0*np.sin(radians(phi0))
    vx_w = 0
    vz_w = 0
    vz = 0
    v = v0
    ay = 0
    ax = 0
    wx = wx
    wz = wz
    rho = rho0 * ((Tb / (Tb + Lb * (y - y0))) ** (1 + (g * M / (R * Lb))))
    vs = 20.05 * np.sqrt(Tb + Lb * (y - y0)) # m/s speed of sound as a function of temperature
    ax_c = -2 * omega * ((vz * sin(L)) + vy * cos(L) * sin(AZ))
    ay_c = 2 * omega * ((vz * cos(L) * cos(AZ)) + vx_w * cos(L) * sin(AZ))
    az_c = -2 * omega * ((vy * cos(L) * cos(AZ)) - vx_w * sin(L))
    Mach = v/vs
    
    """ initializing variables for plots"""
    t_list = [t]
    x_list = [x]
    y_list = [y]
    vy_list = [vy]
    v_list = [v]
    phi0_list = [phi0]
    Mach_list = [Mach]
    
    while y >= 0:
        phi0 = phi0
        """drag calculation with variable density, Temp and sound speed"""
        rho = rho0 * ((Tb / (Tb + Lb * (y - y0))) ** (1 + (g * M / (R *Lb))))
        vs = 20.05 * np.sqrt(Tb + Lb * (y - y0)) # m/s speed of sound as a function of temperature
        Cd3 = K3 / sqrt(v / vs)
        Mach = v/vs
        
        """Determining drag regime"""
        if v > 1.2 * vs: #supersonic
            Cd = Cd3
        elif v < 0.8 * vs: #subsonic
            Cd = Cd1
        else: #transonic
            Cd = ((Cd3 - Cd1)*(v/vs - 0.8)/(0.4)) + Cd1
            
        """Acceleration due to Coriolis"""
        ax_c = -2*omega*((vz_w*sin(L))+ vy*cos(L)*sin(AZ))
        ay_c = 2*omega*((vz_w*cos(L)*cos(AZ))+ vx_w*cos(L)*sin(AZ))
        az_c = -2*omega*((vy*cos(L)*cos(AZ))- vx_w*sin(L))

        """Total acceleration calcs"""
        if vx > 0:
            ax = -0.5*rho*((vx-wx)**2)*Cd*Area/m + ax_c
        else:
            ax = 0

        """ Vy before and after peak"""
        if vy > 0:
            ay = (-0.5 * rho * (vy ** 2) * Cd * Area / m) - g + ay_c
        else:
            ay = (0.5 * rho * (vy ** 2) * Cd * Area / m) - g + ay_c
            az = az_c
            vx = vx + ax*dt # vx without wind
            # vx_w = vx with drag and no wind + wind
            vx_w = vx + 2*wx*(1-(vx/v0*np.cos(radians(phi0))))
            vy = vy + ay*dt
            vz = vz + az*dt
            vz_w = vz + wz*(1-(vx/v0*np.cos(radians(phi0))))
            """projectile velocity"""
            v = sqrt(vx_w**2 + vy**2 + vz**2)
            """new x, y, z positions"""
            x = x + vx_w*dt
            y = y + vy*dt
            z = z + vz_w*dt
            if y_max <= y:
                y_max = y
                phi_impact = degrees(atan(vy/vx)) #impact angle in degrees
                """ appends selected data for ability to plot"""
                t_list.append(t)
                x_list.append(x)
                y_list.append(y)
                vy_list.append(vy)
                v_list.append(v)
                phi0_list.append(phi0)
                Mach_list.append(Mach)
                if y < 0:
                    break
                    t += dt
                    
            """Range table output"""
            table[i] = ('%.f' % phi0, '%.3f' % phi_impact, '%.1f' % x,'%.2f' % z, '%.1f' % y_max, '%.1f' % vx_w,'%.1f' % vz,'%.1f' % vy,'%.1f' % v,'%.2f' %Mach, '%.1f' % t)

    """ Plot"""
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list, label='%d°' % phi0)#plt.plot(x_list, y_list, label='%d°' % phi0)
    plt.title('Altitude versus Range')
    plt.ylabel('Altitude (m)')
    plt.xlabel('Range (m)')
    plt.axis([0, 30000, 0, 15000])
    plt.grid(True)
    
print(table)

legend = plt.legend(title="Firing Angle",loc=0, fontsize='small', fancybox=True)

plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: print `y` in every loop. I suppose that it will stabilize.

Comment: without looking to deeply, i go striaght for the `while` loop. I see one break `if y < 0` so it is probably the case that this condition is not being met.

Answer (score 0):

### Which Editor Should I Use?

Personally, I prefer [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), but [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) is also pretty popular. If you really want to go barebones, try [Vim](https://www.vim.org/download.php). All three are completely free.

### Code Errors

After scanning your code snippet, it appears that you are caught in an infinite loop, which you enter with the statement `while y >= 0`. The reason you always get line 103 when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is likely because that takes the longest, making it more likely to land there at any given time.

Note that currently, you can only escape your `while` loop through this branch:

```py
    if y_max <= y:

        y_max= y
        phi_impact = degrees(atan(vy/vx)) #impact angle in degrees
        """ appends selected data for ability to plot"""
        t_list.append(t)
        x_list.append(x)
        y_list.append(y)
        vy_list.append(vy)
        v_list.append(v)
        phi0_list.append(phi0)
        Mach_list.append(Mach)
        if y < 0:
            break
            t += dt
```

This means that if `ymax` never drops below `y`, or `y` never drops below zero, then you will infinitely loop. Granted, I haven't looked at your code in any great depth, but from the surface it appears that `y_max` is never decremented (meaning it will always be at least equal to `y`). Furthermore, `y` is only updated when you do `y = y + vy*dt`, which will only ever *increase* `y` if `vy >= 0` (I assume `dt` is always positive).

### Debugging

As @Giacomo Catenazzi suggested, try printing out `y` and `y_max` at the top of the `while` loop and see how they change as your code runs. I suspect they are not decrementing like you expected.